# Access mysql for MAMP from command line

Tags: mysql, shell, mamp

I have been learning Ruby on Rails and have been using the command line successfully to view and edit the database (using the `mysql` command).

I am now using MAMP and trying to install Wordpress. It appears that it is using a "different" mysql. I.e., databases I create via the command line aren't viewable in MAMP's phpmyadmin, and vice versa.

How can I access MAMP's mysql via the command line? I'm guessing that I need to specify the host when logging in with the `mysql` command, but I'm not sure what to put there. Since phpmyadmin exists at `localhost:8888/phpMyAdmin`, I tried using `mysql -h localhost:8888 -u root -p`, but that didn't work (error: `Unknown MySQL server host 'localhost:8888'`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MAMP installs it's own MySQL which means that you now have two MySQL instances installed on you machine.

try typing this in your terminal

`/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql`

Answer (score 4):

You can also add this to your a bash_profile so you don't have to write /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql each time by running in terminal :

`sudo vi ~/.bash_profile`

and adding

`alias mysql="/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql"`

Then, from terminal you can run : `mysql -uroot -proot` *notice theres no space for this to work.*